# Why my System.Diagnostics.Process.Start cannot work?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I tried to run my webpage and the `Console.WriteLine` did not work.

Does anyone know why?

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com.sg/");
                Console.WriteLine("Running");
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("run");

        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To me it looks much like you have a WinForms application, not a console application.

Comment: i am creating a window form using VS2013 and i want to open my jsp page using window form. I am doing eye tracking project which also needs to use mysql and ogama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use code like

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
```

Also it's weird to navigate to another in `DocumentCompleted` event. Implement it in button click handler as example.